# Color tag vs Color-scheme tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

In UX.SE, should these tags be the same (synonym) and if not, when would you use one and not the other?

Answer (score 2):

I think they're distinct enough tags not to require a merging / synonyming (if that's a word)

For example, some questions tagged [color](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color) that wouldn't make sense to be [color-scheme](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-scheme) are:

[How to interpret wcag2.0 guidelines on contrast for buttons and icons](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45179/how-to-interpret-wcag2-0-guidelines-on-contrast-for-buttons-and-icons)

[Correction in color model](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45177/correction-in-color-model)

[Intuitive colour pickers for non-expert users?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/41045/intuitive-colour-pickers-for-non-expert-users)

Really, I think [color-scheme](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-scheme) is used more for aesthetic purposes, but [color](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color) is for the *meaning* of certain individual colours and their specific impact on users.

The *real* problem though is with everyone spelling Colour wrong!

Comment: +1 The 2nd and 3rd are good examples, however, the 1st actual seems like a color-scheme related question to me.